# getting fax number from FaxOutgoingJob

Tags: c#, fax

I'm trying to get a fax number from IFaxOutgoingJob but keep getting COM error.

```
FaxServer g_objFaxServer = new FaxServer();
IFaxServer fs = (IFaxServer)g_objFaxServer;

//connection logic...

IFaxOutgoingQueue oq = fs.Folders.OutgoingQueue;
FaxOutgoingJobs jobs = oq.GetJobs();

string fx = "13101230000";

FaxOutgoingMessageIterator iter = oa.GetMessages();
iter.MoveFirst();  //iter = oa oa=>outgoingarchive = already sent
while (!iter.AtEOF)
{
     ...
     if (iter.Message.Recipient.FaxNumber == fx)
     {
         System.Console.WriteLine("orig sched time: {0},  #: {1},  fn: {2}", 
                                         iter.Message.OriginalScheduledTime,
                                         iter.Message.Recipient.FaxNumber,
                                         iter.Message.DocumentName);
     }
     iter.MoveNext();
}
foreach (IFaxOutgoingJob j in jobs)  //jobs=outgoingqueue = to be sent
{
    if (j.Recipient.FaxNumber == fx) // <------------possible error?
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("orig sched time: {0},  #: {1},  fn: {2}", 
                                                  j.OriginalScheduledTime,
                                                  j.Recipient.FaxNumber,
                                                  j.DocumentName);
    }
}
```

I can't really debug in this environment so can't figure out what's going on. Error seems to happen when it's trying to access j.Recipient.FaxNumber because call trace says there's an error, calling IFaxOutgoingJob.get_Recipient().

Side question is FaxOutgoingJob and IFaxOutgoinJob seems to serve the same purpose. Why would one use IFaxOutgoingJob against the other one? I know i is interface but it doesn't really make sense why there are two if they're doing the same thing.

Comment: Just to add to my confusion, when I change IFaxOutgoingJob to FaxOutgoingJob then it says: unable to cast com object of type 'system.__comobject' to interface type 'faxcomexlib.faxoutgoingjob'.... no such interface supported.

Comment: What is the COM error you get when you try to get the recipient?

Comment: The fax server cannot find the job or message by its ID. at FAXCOMEXLib.IFaxOutgoingJob.get_Recipient() at ...Main(String[] args)

Comment: @Mike I'm working on the microsoft fax COM now, and I don't even see all the properties and methods you're using in their documentation.  Do you have an reference links you can share that you've used to create your code?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, at the point when you're trying to read the information, the `Recipient` property isn't available. I would first recommend checking if `j.Recipient == null`, though if your getting an error inside `get_Recipient` that may not help.

The other option is to just wrap the entire block of code in a `try ... catch (COMException ex)' block, and skip the ones where you can't read the recipient. You would need to come back and retry those later somehow.

---

To answer your question about `FaxOutgoingJob` vs `IFaxOutgoingJob`, if you're going to do any kind of COM programming you really need to understand the difference between a class and an interface. But, in a nutshell:

- An interface, like `IFaxOutgoingJob`, is just a contract - it's a list of properties and methods that you can use to talk to some other system in a well-defined way. The interface, by itself, doesn't *do* anything. It merely tell you what you *can* do if you have an object that exposes that interface.
- A class, like `FaxOutgoingJob`, *implements* an interface when it wants to let other people use it. By doing so, it's making the promise that it can do all the things the interface says are possible. It does the real work of making the interface properties and method actually do something.

In COM, interfaces are special because all interaction between COM clients and COM libraries is through interfaces. C# hides all the gory details from you, but if you want to use a COM object, you have to do it through the interface. But in C#, you can't "just use interfaces" because they're not objects -- you can't create them. So, the C# "import library" has created a class who's sole purpose is to be a "skeleton" that the interface can attach to.

You should never really use the class directly, since the COM interface system won't know what to do with it. The only time you ever really need to use a class like that is when you're creating a new object, you would do something like:

```
var newFax = new FaxOutgoingJob as IFaxOutgoingJob;
```

and from them on, use the interface as usual.

Comment: Thanks Michael for your answer. That helps out a lot and you also gave me some ideas on what else to try.

Comment: Checking j.Recipient == null did no good, but I came across something interesting. Windows fax has two out queues, outgoing and outarchive. Names may not be exact but one has pending jobs and the other has sent jobs. My code searches thru outarchive first then outgoing (eg for a job w/ matching recipient fax #). This COM error seems to happen when one of the jobs is in transmission.

Comment: So I start the code when one of the jobs is being sent and while searching outarchive, this job is sent and moved to outarchive. This job is printed as part of outarchive queue then my code searches in the outgoing queue. Then this COM error happens while going thru outgoing queue. I'm thinking it is trying to look for that just-sent job but why? The search thru outgoing queue started AFTER the job was sent. And as I updated the code, I have nothing linking between those two for loops. Any light on this?

Answer (score -1):

Ok I feel bad about this. I think my code has a flaw.

'jobs' in the second for loop block was the old one that I was reusing
and it wasn't being refreshed and that's why it couldn't find it later
when some time has passed (in matter of minutes), especially, 
after a job was sent.